# How do I split a column with one data frame/row into multiple rows (pandas)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Right now, I have a pandas data frame with these column names: School, Year, PostInfo. PostInfo consists of one data frame per row (so a typical row would contain a value from School, a value from Year, and a pandas data frame). How do I expand my data frame such that each row in Post Info also has columns with its associated School and Year values?

Currently: 
**School**    **Year**    **PostInfo**

Each df in the PostInfo column contains columns **user_id**, **time_stamp**, **comment**. I'm trying to expand the data frame into something like this:

**School**    **Year**    **User_Id**     **Time_Stamp**     **Comment**

Comment: Can you post some example data? Have you looked at `melt`, `pivot_table`, `unstack` etc?

Comment: I edited my question—should be clearer now.

Comment: Please post an example dataframe. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You need to post code so we can recreate what you have i.e. `df = pd.DataFrame(???)`